# Choosing none in set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Invariant (UniqueID, characteristic1, characteristic2)
Variant   (VariantID, UniqueID, specification1, specification2)
```

Each project has its own unchanging characteristics between implementations. Each implementation also has its own individual properties.

So, I use queries like this to find projects with the given characteristics and specifications:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Invariants` 
LEFT JOIN (`Variants`) ON (`Variants`.`UniqueID`=`Invariants`.`UniqueID`)   
WHERE char2='y' and spec1='x' 
GROUP BY `Invariant`.`UniqueID`;
```

I'm looking for a query that will return all projects that have never satisfied a given specification. So, if one of project 100's variants had `spec1='bad'`, then I don't want project 100 to be included, regardless if it had variants where `spec1='good'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from Invariants iv
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Variants v
    where v.UniqueId = iv.UniqueId and v.spec1 = 'bad'
)
```

The queries below do not address your question, I probably read to fast and thought you wanted to pick up only the invariant properties of a particular type. But I will note that you shouldn't use a left join and then filter, in the `where` clause, against columns from the right table (except for checking nulls). People make that mistake all the time and that's what jumped out to me at first glance.

The whole purpose of a left join is that some of the rows will not match and will thus have filler null values in the columns for the right-hand table. This join logic happens first and then after that the `where` clause is applied. When you have a condition like `where spec1 = 'x'` it will always evaluate to false against a null value. So you end up eliminating all the rows you wanted to keep.

This happens a lot with these invariant/custom values tables. You're only interested in one of the properties but if you don't filter prior to joining or inside the join condition, you end up dropping rows because the value didn't exist and you didn't have a value left to compare once it tried to apply a `where`-clause condition on the property name.

Hope that made sense. See below for examples:

```
select iv.UniqueId, ...
from
    Invariants iv left outer join
    Variants
        on v.UniqueId = vi.UniqueId and v.spec1 = 'x'
```

or

```
select iv.UniqueId, ...
from
    Invariants iv left outer join
    (    
        select
        from Variants
        where spec1 = 'x'
    ) v
        on v.UniqueId = vi.UniqueId
```

Comment: I tried this:
SELECT * FROM iv LEFT JOIN v ON (v.UniqueID=iv.UniqueID and v.spec1 NOT LIKE 'bad') WHERE iv.char1=6 group by iv.uniqueid; and I got nulls in the place where 'bad' would normally be - but it still included the bad records

Comment: What you said worked! Thanks. I don't quite follow your sentence that begins with "But I will not..." Could you clarify what you mean? Is there something wrong with where clauses with joins?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with where clauses with joins. It's specific to left join and filtering on the right table. By doing so basically results in an inner join.

Comment: I added a few paragraphs to explain better.